# android the path method with the overlay items

Tags: android

Android I add a path ( line by entering two location ) this code is done in my HelloOverlayItem class ! the problem is when i put this method no overlay items appear just the path and when i remove it the overlay items appear her is the method

```
enter code here
    public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
{


GeoPoint     p = new GeoPoint((int) (29.98703241482666 * 1E6), (int) ( 31.439915891647359 * 1E6));
GeoPoint     p2=new GeoPoint((int) (29.987107515335083 * 1E6), (int) ( 31.43912136554718 * 1E6));
//GeoPoint   p3 = new GeoPoint((int) (29.98703241482666 * 1E6), (int) ( 31.439915891647359 * 1E6));
//GeoPoint   p4=new GeoPoint((int) (29.987107515335083 * 1E6), (int) ( 31.43912136554718 * 1E6));
  // Let's assume you've assigned values to these two GeoPoints now.

  Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
  Point startingPoint = projection.toPixels(p, null);
  Point endingPoint = projection.toPixels(p2, null);
     //point startingPoint1 = projection.toPixels(p3, null);
     //Point endingPoint2 = projection.toPixels(p4, null);
     // Create the path containing the line between the two points.
  Path path = new Path();

  path.moveTo(startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y);
  path.lineTo(endingPoint.x, endingPoint.y);

  // Setup the paint.  You'd probably do this outside of the draw() method to be more efficient.
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setColor(Color.RED);

 // mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
 // mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
  //mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
  //mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
  // Can set other paint characteristics, such as width, anti-alias, color, etc....

  // Draw the path!
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've overriden the superclass  draw() method. You need to call it in your method with:

```
super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
```